# Angular and ASP.NET Core wrong api request on wrong port

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

I'm building a new Angular app with an ASP.NET Core backend. The requests (via `HttpClient.Get` in the Angular app) work fine when I'm using the default `WeatherForecastController`, nevertheless when I create a new `BaseController`, its route is unreachable.

I found that I could access it via another port (7188 instead of 4200) but it doesn't seem logical to do that, would you have any idea how to fix that?

In my Angular app, I should be able to call my API for a new controller like it works for the default controller :

```
http.get<User[]>('/weatherforecast') => It works
http.get<User[]>('/demo') => It doesn't works
```

(Of course the structure of the controller is exactly the same as the default controller)

[DemoController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZE3iM.png)

[WeatherForecastController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/876xk.png)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. [Please do not post screenshots of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). Instead, copy and paste the relevant code in [code fences](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362/6621862).

Comment: Have you checked if there any error occured during your call? Could you please share more details about how you are calling the API from your angular app? I mean the HttpClientModule, and your  Service Component details.

Comment: Based on your comment, if your API route includes `[Route("api/[controller]")]` then you should call by `api/*` but if your controller route is like  [Route("[controller]")] then you should be able to reach by `/WeatherForecast` or `/demo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if your file proxy.conf.js contains the `context` property route to this controller. If not add it the same as it is done for the weatherforecast one. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you ! It works, I also changed the line with '/weatherforecast' by '/api/**' to handle every requests starting by '/api/'.

Comment: @AnthonyDubois mark it as accepted so it might help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

> I found that I could access it via another port (7188 instead of 4200)
> but it doesn't seem logical to do that, would you have any idea how to
> fix that?

Based on your comment, if your API route includes `[Route("api/[controller]")]` then you should call by `api/*` but if your controller route is like  `[Route("[controller]")]` then you should be able to reach by `/WeatherForecast` or `/demo`

For instance:

Angular Function:

```
  demoAPI = "";
  weatherAPI = [];
  demoAPIUrl = "https://localhost:7223/Demo/demo";
  weatherAPIURl = "https://localhost:7223/WeatherForecast";

  GetWeatherData() {
   
    this.http.get<any[]>(this.weatherAPIURl)
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.weatherAPI = data;
    });
       
  }
  GetDemoData() {
   
    this.http.get<any>(this.demoAPIUrl)
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.demoAPI = data;
        console.log(data);
      });
  }
```

Web API:

```
  [ApiController]
  [Route("[controller]")]
  public class DemoController : ControllerBase
  {
      [HttpGet]
      [Route("demo")]
      public IActionResult GetDemo()
      {
          return Ok(new { Message = "This is the demo endpoint" });
      }
  }
```

Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
        builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200") // Update with your Angular app's URL
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowAnyMethod());
});
```

Middleware:

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCors("AllowSpecificOrigin");
app.UseAuthorization();
```

Output:

[image]